# DEB package: Shell script with debconf does not show input dialog

Tags: package-management, dpkg, debconf

The following *config* script inside *control.tar.gz*

```
#!/bin/sh -e

. /usr/share/debconf/confmodule

db_fset mailadmin/database_host seen false
db_clear
db_purge

db_input medium mailadmin/database_host || true
db_go

db_get mailadmin/database_host
echo "$RET" > /tmp/from_config_script.txt

exit 0
```

with the template

```
Template: mailadmin/database_host
Type: string
Description: The database server's host name or IP address.
```

(file *templates*) does not show an input dialog when I install the package using *dpkg -i*, and when I run it from the command line as well.

Instead it writes "localhost" to */tmp/from_config_script.txt*, even though this default value is not part of the template file any more. I never ever saw the input popup. The input popup is what I am trying to achieve.

I removed the package with *apt-get purge mailadmin*, but even purge did not clear this default value. What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
db_input high ...
```

This is not mentioned in the tutorial at http://www.fifi.org ( http://www.fifi.org/doc/debconf-doc/tutorial.html ), only in an indirect manner.

A priority of *medium* is too low for showing the dialog. The threshold priority must be set somewhere on the computer. Unfortunately I still do not know where. But at least I know how to make the dialogs work.

Answer (score 1):

After following the suggestion listed in the earlier answer, my config script would still not run no dialogs prompts etc.   I finally stumbled across this comment in the following manpage article (see section The PostInst Script)

https://manpages.debian.org/testing/debconf-doc/debconf-devel.7.en.html

> Always source /usr/share/debconf/confmodule at the top of your
>   postinst, even if you won't be running any db_* commands in it. This
>   is required to make sure the config script gets a chance to run (see
>   HACKS for details).

Once I sourced the confmodule in postinst (even though I am not calling db_* commands here) my config script began to work as expected